# C# Cannot Create Directory

Tags: c#, .net, create-directory

I can't seem to get the following code to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace TechKit
{
   class CsvWriter
   {
      public static void csvLogWrite(string ADName, string LogTimeStamp, string LogEntry, string ATOW, string SSC, string Specialty)
      {
         string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Properties.Settings.Default.TechKitSDFLocation);
         dirPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, "Logs", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

         try
         {
            // Determine whether the directory exists. 
            if (Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Log Path Exisits - Using It");
               return;
            }

            // Try to create the directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            Console.WriteLine("The Log directory was created successfully at {0}.", Directory.GetCreationTime(dirPath));

         }

         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("The directory creation process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
         }

         finally { }

         string newFileName = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + ".csv";
         string combinedPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, newFileName);
         string logDetails = LogTimeStamp + "," + Specialty + "," + ADName + "," + LogEntry + Environment.NewLine;

         if (!File.Exists(combinedPath))
         {
            string logHeader = "Timestamp,Specialty,Name,Log Entry" + Environment.NewLine;
            File.WriteAllText(newFileName, logHeader);
         }

         File.AppendAllText(combinedPath, logDetails);
         Console.WriteLine("Data Written To CSV FIle:");
         Console.WriteLine(logDetails);
         Console.WriteLine("****************************");
      }
   }
}
```

The code fires an exception when it tries to write the non-existant directory. I get:

```
'A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll'
```

in the console also.   I'm a relative newbie, so I am at a loss.  I can write a file just fine, just not create a directory.

Thanks...

Comment: What is the initial value of dirPath when you read it from the properties settings?

Comment: do you have a colon ':' in your dirPath? That will cause it

Comment: Have you tried instantiating the class and THEN using it?  `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);`

Comment: Add a Console.WriteLine() on your dirpath, interested to see what it is, if it's rooted or not.

Comment: Ok.  Checked the inital value of dirPath.  I feel stupid.  It is a connectionstring and had 'data source=' in front of the path.  A little string magic to remove and all is good.  Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Directory Path 
And then check It's read/write rights.

And then use a code something like this

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);

or 

System.IO.Director.CreateDirectory("Path to directory" )
```

Comment: I'll check as the answer, but it was an oversight on my part as noted in the above comment I left.  Thanks!